# MVC3 DropDownListFor - a simple example?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm having trouble with `DropDownListFor` in my MVC3 app.   I was able to use StackOverflow to figure out how to get them to appear on the View, but now I don't know how to capture the values in its corresponding properties on the View Model when it's submitted.  In order to get this to work I had to create an inner class that had an ID and a value property, then I had to use an `IEnumerable<Contrib>` to satisfy the `DropDownListFor` parameter requirements.   Now, however, how is MVC FW supposed to map the value that is selected on this drop-down back into the simple string property on my view model?

```
public class MyViewModelClass
{
    public class Contrib
    {
        public int ContribId { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Contrib> ContribTypeOptions = 
        new List<Contrib>
        {
            new Contrib {ContribId = 0, Value = "Payroll Deduction"},
            new Contrib {ContribId = 1, Value = "Bill Me"}
        };

    [DisplayName("Contribution Type")]
    public string ContribType { get; set; }
}
```

In my View I place the dropdown on the page like this:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ContribType)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ContribTypeOptions.First().ContribId, 
             new SelectList(Model.ContribTypeOptions, "ContribId", "Value"))
</div>
```

When I submit the form the `ContribType` is (of course) null.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 166, accepted):

You should do like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ContribType, 
                new SelectList(Model.ContribTypeOptions, 
                               "ContribId", "Value"))
```

Where:

```
m => m.ContribType
```

is a property where the result value will be.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!  Sergey, this is exactly what I have been looking for for many hours.

Comment: Thanks :) for your answer Is there any way to show "-- Select--" from here. ?

Comment: @VeeKeyBee, you can add new item to the list `contribTypeOptions`, for example `new Contrib {ContribId = -1, Value = "Please Select"}` and it will be shown in dropdown list. Than you can check if `ContribType` is `-1` this is means that user haven't selected any value

Comment: that the way I am just doing .. But for dropdownlist we can give some options

Comment: You can do this: `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ContribType, new SelectList(Model.ContribTypeOptions, "ContribId", "Value", Model.ContribTypeOptions.First().ContribId), "Select, please")`

Comment: @SergeyGavruk. This answer has been used as a dupe on a few recent questions but is confusing some users because of the statement _And the last param of Select list constructor is a selected value_ - The last parameter is ignored by the method (which internally builds its own `SelectList`). Its the value of the property (`ContribType`) which determines what is selected (that's how model binding works) and the code should just be `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ContribType, new SelectList(Model.ContribTypeOptions, "ContribId", "Value")` Can you please edit the answer to correct.

Comment: Can anyone please let me know how to use this solution when dropdown values are coming from database?

Answer (score 6):

For binding Dynamic Data in a DropDownList you can do the following:

Create ViewBag in Controller like below

```
ViewBag.ContribTypeOptions = yourFunctionValue();
```

now use this value in view like below:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ContribType, 
    new SelectList(@ViewBag.ContribTypeOptions, "ContribId", 
                   "Value", Model.ContribTypeOptions.First().ContribId), 
    "Select, please")
```

Answer (score 6):

I think this will help :
In Controller get the list items and selected value

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    ItemsStore item = itemStoreRepository.FindById(id);
    ViewBag.CategoryId = new SelectList(categoryRepository.Query().Get(), 
                                        "Id", "Name",item.CategoryId);

    // ViewBag to pass values to View and SelectList
    //(get list of items,valuefield,textfield,selectedValue)

    return View(item);
}
```

and in View

```
@Html.DropDownList("CategoryId",String.Empty)
```

Comment: It's usually not a god pattern to expose your repository to the View like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
     @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedValue,Your List,"ID","Values")
```

Here Value is that object of model where you want to save your Selected Value