# DropDownListFor null value, reference used

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

So I've looked around StackOverflow a lot and found a nice solution to my problem.

[MVC3 DropDownListFor - a simple example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142961/mvc3-dropdownlistfor-a-simple-example), this ought to do it for me. BUT, it returned a null value... Somehow I have no idea how to go around this so assistance will be appreciated.

**Model AccountModel.cs**

```
...
public string Address { get; set; }
public string City { get; set; }

public class StateList
{
    public int StateID { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<StateList> StateListOptions = new List<StateList>
{
    //new StateList { StateID = -1, Value = "Select State" },
    new StateList { StateID = 0, Value = "NY" },
    new StateList { StateID = 1, Value = "PO" }
};

public string State { get; set; }

public string Zip { get; set; }
...
```

**Register.cshtml**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.State, new SelectList(Model.StateListOptions, "StateID", "Value", Model.StateListOptions.First().StateID))
```

I thought maybe my `StateID = -1` made it output a null for some reason... but it didn't, you can see it commented out here. What did I do wrong?!

**Get Action**

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
    ViewData["PasswordLength"] = MembershipService.MinPasswordLength;

    return View();
}
```

Comment: how does your GET action looks like ?

Comment: I've added the Action in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an object of your Model/ ViewModel and send that to view.

```
public ActionResult Register()
{    
    AccountModel vm=new AccountModel();

    //Not sure Why you use ViewData here.Better make it as a property
    // of your AccountModel class and pass it.
    ViewData["PasswordLength"] = MembershipService.MinPasswordLength;

    return View(vm);
}
```

Now your View should be strongly typed to this Model

So in your `Register.cshtml` view,

```
@model AccountModel
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
   //Other form elements also
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.State, new SelectList(Model.StateListOptions, 
                                                "StateID", "Value")"Select")
   <input type="submit" />

}
```

To Get the Selected State in POST, You can check the `State` Property value.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(AccountModel model)
{
   if(ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      // Check for Model.State property value here for selected state   
      // Save and Redirect (PRG Pattern)
   }
   return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Ok I've added the object of my model and it worked. But it saves the `StateID` instead of `Value`. How to fix that ? :S

Comment: @user1407758: Swap the Order of StateID and Value in the Html.DropDownListFor call in your view.( Value should comes first)