# html.dropdownlistfor() troubles...getting null reference exceptions

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html.dropdownlistfor

I've tried to follow a few examples from here and a couple other resources to just create a very simple member in my viewmodel and display it as a dropdown list on my view with a dropdownlistfor() helper.  I can't seem to wrap my head around it and it's not working with what I'm trying.

here's my viewmodel:

```
public class Car
{
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyViewModel
{


    public IEnumerable<Car> Cars = new List<Car> { 
        new Car {
            CarId = 1,
            Name = "Volvo"
        },
        new Car {
            CarId = 2,
            Name = "Subaru"
        }
    };


    public int MyCarId { get; set; }
}
```

and here is my view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MyCarId, new SelectList(Model.Cars, "CarId", "Name"))
```

and here is my controller:

```
public ActionResult MyView()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142961/mvc3-dropdownlistfor-a-simple-example

Comment: that's actually the example I followed (almost to the letter).  Initially I had it set up identically to that but got the same result so I tried pulling out the car class from within the MyViewModel class.  Still getting null reference exceptions.

Comment: Can you add your `Controller` code to your question?

Comment: added the controller code which, after reading the two responses below, was too vanilla....testing them now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you send the Model to your View:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var myViewModel = new MyViewModel()

    return View(myViewModel);
}
```

And in your View you need to make sure you're defining your Model:

```
@model namespace.MyViewModel
```

Comment: this got me there thanks much.  Question though, I had some other members in my viewmodel (for labels and textboxes etc) that were being rendered just fine w/o passing the in the instance of the viewmodel.  Why does the dropdownlist require that the instance be passed in and the others do not?

Comment: @ChristopherJohnson Couldn't tell you that without seeing your full code.

Answer (score 1):

You example works fine, I think you forgot to send MyViewModel in POST Action.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
{
    return View(model);
}
```