# Set selected item of DropDownListFor in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In my ASP MVC site I want to be able to select a default drop down list item in the view. However, the overload I'm currently using seems to just add another item to the drop down list instead of specifying which one I want selected.

Here is the code in the controller that created the `SelectList`

```
SelectList tmpList = new SelectList(new[] { "", "SAF", "SNY" });
ViewBag.Companies = tmpList;
```

And here is the code in the view. This, however, just winds up adding an extra `SAF` to the list like the screen shot below shows.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AgencyCompany1, (SelectList)ViewBag.Companies, "SAF")
```

[image]

Comment: Check out this nice example

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142961/mvc3-dropdownlistfor-a-simple-example

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your controller, where the second "SAF" is where you are setting the selected object:

```
ViewBag.list = new SelectList(new[] { "", "SAF", "SNY" }, "SAF");
```

And in your view (you don't need the last "SAF" parameter anymore):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AgencyCompany1, (SelectList)ViewBag.Companies)
```