# Why is my default value for DropDownListFor not working properly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, html.dropdownlistfor

For whatever reason, my default value for my Html.DropDownListFor isn't working:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DomainList,
    new SelectList(Model.DomainList, "DomainId", "Name", Model.SingleDomain.DomainId),
    new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Any idea why?

**UPDATE**

With the answer below, I updated my code to the following:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedDomain, 
    new SelectList(Model.DomainList, "DomainId", "Name", Model.SelectedDomain),
    "Select a Domain", 
    new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Is the value of Model.SingleDomain.DomainId in the list of values in model.DomainList?

Comment: Yes.  Even if I input a value I know exists instead of that variable, the dropdownlist doesn't set the default value.

Comment: Also, generally when you do a DropDownListFor, it is for an int (to store the selected value), not the List itself. Meaning it should read something like: @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.DomainId, ....)

Comment: Sure, but any clue as to why the default selected item won't work?

Comment: Did you try my last comments suggestion?

Comment: You are binding your Drop Down Lists selected item to a list which does not make sense. You need to bind it to an int id.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

In your ViewModel, add an integer to store the selected domain id:

```
public int SelectedDomainId { get; set; }
```

Change your DropDownListFor to:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedDomainId,
    new SelectList(Model.DomainList, "DomainId", "Name", Model.SingleDomain.DomainId),
    new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Now on your post-back the selected id will be posted in SelectedDomainId.

Or, you could add the single domain object to your VM (to indicate which one was selected):

```
public Domain SelectedDomain { get; set; }
```

And change your DropDownListFor to:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedDomain,
        new SelectList(Model.DomainList, "DomainId", "Name", Model.SingleDomain.DomainId),
        new { @class = "form-control" })
```

I usually use the selected ID, but I think either should work

Here is another good example:

[MVC3 DropDownListFor - a simple example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142961/mvc3-dropdownlistfor-a-simple-example?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

my problem solved  when change viewbag.xxxxxxx to
viewbag.xxxxxxx1 issue  was hapend when model propety and viewbag property was same.

controller :

```
 ViewBag.serviceid = new SelectList(db.services.ToList(), "id", "titel", package.service_id);
```

view:

```
     @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.service_id, ViewBag.serviceid as SelectList, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone is having trouble with `Html.DropdownList` keep in mind that

`@Html.DropDownList("Country", ViewBag.Country as List<SelectListItem>)` --> doesn't select the default value

`@Html.DropDownList("Countries", ViewBag.Country as List<SelectListItem>)` --> selects the default value

For more details, see: http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/69395e7d-7c7c-4318-97f5-4ea108a0da97.aspx