# Get Navigation Properties id's in action method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, navigation-properties

I have 3 models names images,game and imageviewmodel

```
public class game
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]

    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<images> Image { get; set; }

}
public class images
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]

    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]
    public string Image1Url { get; set; }
    public virtual game Game { get; set; }

}
public class ImageViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    public HttpPostedFileBase ImageUpload { get; set; }
    public virtual game Game { get; set; }

}
public class GameDb : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<game> Games { get; set; }
    public DbSet<images> Images { get; set; }
 }
```

My view is strongly typed view of imageviewmodel . I have a dropdown list there with all games filled Here is my GET create method

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.GameId = new SelectList(db.Games, "Id", "Name");
            return View(new ImageViewModel());
        }
```

my dropdown is filled with GenreId

```
 <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("GameId","Select an Item")
        </div
```

On my POST create method I want to access dropdown value id to insert in image table

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(ImageViewModel model)
         {
         }
```

I am unable to access game id of drop down list.I am doing like this

```
var img=new images{

Game.( no intellisense) =model.Game.id,

};
```

How do I resolve that need some help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all consider follow the [naming convensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229040(v=vs.110).aspx) when you name your classes.

Second, consider using `DropDownListFor` helper method instead of `DropDownList`

And finally you have to create new `Game` object instance before set it's id:

```
var img = new images
{
   Game = new game { Id = model.Game.Id }
};
```

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. it gives this error on your code

Comment: Seems `Game` object of your model is `null`. So your binding doesn't work, try to use `DropDownListFor` binding, you can find simple example in this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142961/mvc3-dropdownlistfor-a-simple-example)

Comment: BTW do you really need `Game` object in your `ImageViewModel`? You should replace it with simple `GameId` property

Comment: How do I get that id filled with what I have selected in drop down?

Comment: I am uploading image and want to insert ID of game in image table

Comment: 1. You don't want to save `HttpPostedFileBase` in the database, you need to save file to the hard drive and store path to it in DB as `string`.

Comment: Yes I dont post that code here it is saving in a folder but how to get id of game selected in dropdown list. I am using this link for upload image http://cpratt.co/file-uploads-in-asp-net-mvc-with-view-models/

Comment: You should have `GameId` in your `ImageViewModel` and create new `game` like `var img = new images { Game = new game { Id =  model.GameId, ImageUrl = 'path to the image' } };`

Comment: What to do with Name field of game?

Comment: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.