# MVC creating an attribute based on dropdownlist

Tags: html, model-view-controller

I want to create a static dropdownlist as such

```
@Html.dropdownlist("Category", new List<SelectListItem>
{
new SelectListItem{value = "1", Text = "All"},
new SelectListItem{value = "2", Text = "Amy" }
})
```

I want to map this category to my object class so that I am able to access that attribute when running the query at my query page and do a switch-case in order to do different things based on different dropdownlist items selected.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142961/mvc3-dropdownlistfor-a-simple-example for a starting point.

Comment: @Rday okay i used that piece of codes but I am only getting a count for that even when i select option 2. How do i get the option 2 value id?

Comment: can you include your model class and action method? It could be a binding issue.