# Dropdown using MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

Hi I am relatively new to MVC. I am building one application where I need to fill a drop down list.
I have to fill values from Properties mentioned below,

```
public class Data
{
    public string to_node_id { get; set; }
    public Datacenter datacenter { get; set; }
    public string data_type { get; set; }
    public string msg_id { get; set; }
    public string from_type { get; set; }
    public string from_node_id { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public Data data { get; set; }
} 

public class Datacenter
{
    public string order_id { get; set; }
    public string lastmodify { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string order_type { get; set; }

}
```

Please can anyone help.

I am using razor syntax.

Comment: Use `SelectListItem` collection to bind your viewmodel into drop down list. Show what you've tried in view side for doing so.

Answer (score 0):

It's like :

```
@{
       List<SelectListItem> listItems= new List<SelectListItem>();
       listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
              Text = "Exemplo1",
              Value = "Exemplo1"
            });
       listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "Exemplo2",
                Value = "Exemplo2",
                Selected = true
            });
       listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "Exemplo3",
                Value = "Exemplo3"
            });
    }

    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.order, listItems, "-- Select Order--")
```

Answer (score 0):

The [DropDownListFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142961/mvc3-dropdownlistfor-a-simple-example) (or [DropDownList](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc)) with [SelectList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx) is the way to go.

I would suggest to create the selectList in the action in the controller (instead of the view) and send it to the View by the [ViewBag](http://rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp-net-mvc-3-applications/) (or ViewData) as it is how Microsoft does it when Visual Studio generates a CRUD form.

Answer (score 0):

Use viewbag to pass data as below, You can write in controller
For static list

```
var genderlist = new List<SelectListItem>
{
   new SelectListItem { code = "M", name = "Male" },
   new SelectListItem { code = "F", name = "Female" }                
};
viewbag.genderlist=genderlist;
```

same as above you can pass dynamic listing too

Now in your view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.gender, new SelectList(ViewBag.genderlist, "code", "name"));
```

Thats it!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I don't want to provide any values. I just want to show all the properties in the drop down.

Comment: Do you need combination of values in dropdown like <option value="1">John doe - male </option> ? Please explain your question.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote about dropdown lists in here: http://davidsonsousa.net/en/post/the-best-way-to-use-dropdownlistfor-with-aspnet-mvc

But in general I create my dropdown lists by having:

1. Editor Templates - I can control the look/feel or customize using javascript
2. A helper class - I can control what data is going to be loaded into the dropdown list
3. A ViewModel to transfer the data from the Controller to the View

The most important here is the helper class. And why is that? For 2 reasons:

1. Because you will need to load the values from somewhere: DB, text file, web service or even hard coded
2. You will not have only one dropdown in your project

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery function for this dropdown list

```
<select id="dropDown"><select>
var urlpath = '@Url.Action("LoadModule", "MenuOperation")';

$.ajax({
    url: urlpath,
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    type: "Get",
    success: function (data) {
        $('#dropDown').empty();
        $('#dropDown').append("<option value='0'>--Select--</option>");
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

            $("#dropDown").append($("<option></option>").val(data[i].Value).html(data[i].Name));
        }
    }
});
```